# when characteristic $p = 2$, $x^p - a^p = (x-a)^p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

With characteristic $p = 2$ we have $x^p + a^p = (x+a)^p$.
The proof comes from applying the binomial theorem and then the coefficients are divided by $p$ for $0 < n < p-1$. It satisfies $x^p - a^p = (x-a)^p$ also when $p$ is prime (odd), but when $p$ is $2$, I get $(x-a)^2 = x^2-2 a x + a^2 = x^2 + a^2$.
Is this correct? is there any condition I am missing that p cannot be 2 or anything?

Comment: It's true in every field of prime characteristic. It's the Frobenius endomorphism and the normal way to prove it is by considering the binomial expansion of $(x+a)^p$ and noticing all the intermediate terms must be zero. If the field is finite or perfect then this will be an automorphism.

Comment: In characteristic $2$, $-1=1$, so $x^2-a^2=x^2+a^2$.